# Change SVG image color using Css or do it manually in SVG file

Tags: html, css, svg, background, background-color

I have a svg picture file, but the content inside is black, and I need a white, I tried to add `background-color` property to style attribute of svg file, but Image still black, I trying to find solution in Internet, and I found, but I cant use jQuery or some native JavaScript for it. Can somebody help me? Thanks!

P.S. If you need more info just ask me.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I use `.svg` files for `<img>` tag, and css-way dont worked for me. I use `fill` attribute for `<path>` tag inside `.svg` file.